# Hash.delete_if returning removed elements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

From a Hash `relations` I want to remove some entries and keep the ones I removed in another Hash `obj`.

I found `Hash.delete_if` and did:

```
obj = relations.delete_if{|k,v| v[:value] == 1}
```

However, instead of returning the ones that are removed, it returns the ones that are *not* removed.

Is there a method that does that?

Comment: Try with `select` ? : `obj_with_value_eq_one = relations.select{ |k, v| v[:value] == 1 }`

Comment: @MrYoshiji: yeah, but what about the deletion part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
another_hash = {}
relations.delete_if{|k,v| v == 1 ? another_hash[k] = v; true : false}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`partition` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition):

```
{x: 1, y: 0, z: 2, t: 1}.partition {|k, v| v == 1}
# => [[[:x, 1], [:t, 1]], [[:y, 0], [:z, 2]]]
```

You would then have to turn the results back into hashes, for which you can use the [`Hash[]` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D):

```
{x: 1, y: 0, z: 2, t: 1}.partition{|k, v| v == 1}.map{|h| Hash[h]}
# => [{:x => 1, :t => 1}, {:y => 0, :z => 2}]
```

So to do what you were asking:

```
obj, relations = relations.partition{|k, v| v[:value] == 1}.map{|h| Hash[h]}
```

Comment: you can use `map(&:to_h)` instead of `map{|h| Hash[h]}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a built-in method that does this, but building the method yourself is trivial.

```
def delete_and_return relations, &block
  [relations.reject(&block), relations.select(&block)]
end


relations = {
  a: {value: 1},
  b: {value: 2},
  c: {value: 1},
}



kept, deleted = delete_and_return(relations) {|k,v| v[:value] == 1}

kept # => {:b=>{:value=>2}}
deleted # => {:a=>{:value=>1}, :c=>{:value=>1}}
```

You can even open `Hash` class and put the method there.